# Как работать с SVG спрайтами на сайте?

Tags: css, css3, svg, svg-спрайт

Суть проблемы, есть svg иконки (спрайт) сохранённые как один документ .svg, пытаюсь подключить их к сайту, т.е. вывести прямо в коде HTML. Для этого тегам  в svg файле задал уникальные идентификаторs id="icon1, icon2 .... iconN" вначале вставлял иконки с использование тега  так:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" >
  <use fill="none" stroke="white" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/sprite.svg#icon1"></use>
</svg>
```

Но всплыла такая проблема, толщина линий в svg сбрасывалась до 1 пикселя и иконка вместо такого вида http://joxi.ru/krDpEXRI05ZDdr становилась такой http://joxi.ru/52a1M7BtGxD112 .

Нашёл другой вариант вставки с помощью тега :

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" width="200" height="200" data="svg/sprite.svg#icon1"></object>
```

Теперь загружается вся svg-шка только с помощью css все кроме активного элемента  - скрываются. При таком варианте не переопределяется CSS, сохраняется толщина линий, но так же не получается переопределить и другие стили (цвет например). В общем проблема. Скажите как нужно вставлять SVG спрайт на сайт так, чтобы сохранялись все его исходные стили, а так же была возможность их переопределения (на событие hover например) и удобного позиционирования (если слои расположены не друг под другом). И возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Тут несколько подводных камней**:

1. Как только вы используете команду "Use" элементы спрайта попадают в shadow DOM и внешними стилями уже невозможно, что-то переопределить.
2. Стили, прописанные непосредственно в элементах SVG имеют наивысший приоритет -(path id=""  fill="blue" stroke="grey" stoke-width="2")
   Поэтому их невозможно изменить ни через style внутри файла SVG, ни через внешние таблицы стилей.

**Пробуйте порешать проблему:**

1. Удалить стили внутри SVG файла
2. Определить стили во внешней таблице стилей
3. Разместить таблицу стилей в той же директории, что и SVG файлы. Это обязательно.
4. Добавьте во внешней таблице стилей для path { fill:inherit; stroke-width:inherit; stroke:inherit;} Это решает проблему shadow DOM. 
   Остальное вы все делаете правильно: подключение через object
5. Внутри SVG спрайта оберните каждую иконку в отдельный symbol id="icon1"

После этого всё должно заработать.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно тегами рисовать графику.
Хотя я рекомендую обратить внимание на [canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_canvas.asp) т.к. он (уже) отрисовывается прямо в видеокарте.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <rect x="25" y="25" width="200" height="200" fill="lime" stroke-width="4" stroke="pink" />
  <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="75" fill="orange" />
  <polyline points="50,150 50,200 200,200 200,100" stroke="red" stroke-width="4" fill="none" />
  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="200" y2="200" stroke="blue" stroke-width="4" />
</svg>
```