# canvas не рисует svg в firefox

Tags: svg, canvas, firefox, svg-спрайт, html5-canvas

Cnavas в firefox не рисует SVG если это спрайт, то есть SVG запрашивается не так `/icons-sprite.svg`, а так `/icons-sprite.svg#usd-usage` (то есть мы говорим что нам нужен конкретный фрагмент #usd-usage)

```
let img = new Image();
        img.onload = () => {
          cx.drawImage(img, 7, h-5, 20, 20);
        };
        img.src = '/icons-sprite.svg#usd-usage';
```

если я пробую рисовать другой svg файл, не спрайт то все нормально.

Думал что проблема может быть в `xlink:href` заменил на просто `href`
не помогло

https://jsfiddle.net/ko9rL91z/2/ - пример

https://pastebin.com/6LK58Xw5 - пример SVG

Есть идеи в чем проблема?
в хроме все просто замечательно.

Answer (score 3):

Проблемы с подключением спрайта у Firefox, как и у других браузеров могут возникать по многим причинам, но об этом позже.

**Подключение спрайта в html через тег `<object>`:**

```html
 <object type="image/svg+xml" data="http://svgshare.com/i/2X7.svg#usd-usage" width="200" height="200"> </object>
```

В сниппете не работает, но если сохранить этот код в отдельный файл html, то работает в Firefox и Chrome.

**Подключение спрайта в html через тег `<img>`:**

```html
<body>
 <img src="http://svgshare.com/i/2X7.svg#usd-usage" width="200" height="200" alt="image description">
</body>
```

**Подключение спрайта в html с помощью `background-image`:**

```html
<body>
<style>
.container 
{
width:200px;
height:200px;
    background-image: url("http://svgshare.com/i/2X7.svg#usd-usage");
}
</style>
<div class="container"> </div>
 
</body>
```

Обратите внимание, что для всех способов подключения svg, как отдельного файла в html **указаны, тем или иным способом ширина и высота.** К этому чувствителен прежде всего Firefox.  Более подробно о других способах подключения svg файлов [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047)

- Другим источником проблем с видимостью спрайта, очень часто бывает
  сам спрайт

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <style>
     .sprite-symbol-usage {display: none;}
     .sprite-symbol-usage:target {display: inline;}
    </style>
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 500 500" id="usd">
   <path d="m 145,312 c -2,69 31,100 104,102 78,1 113,-34 109,-101 -6,-58 -62,-73 -106,-79 -48,-17 -99,-25 -99,-95 0,-48 32,-79 99,-78 60,0 97,25 96,84" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:40" />
   <path d="m 250,15 0,470" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:30" />
  </symbol>
 </defs>
<use id="usd-usage" xlink:href="#usd" class="sprite-symbol-usage" /></svg>
```

Из-за стилей: `.sprite-symbol-usage {display: none;}` картинка будет не видна.
Какая-то пара тегов `<defs>.. </defs>` либо `<symbol>.. </symbol>` явно лишняя, так как выполняют одну и ту же фунцкцию - спрятать изображение до вызова командой `use`
Так как вы не можете редактировать файл на чужом ресурсе, то лучше скачать его и привести в порядок:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 viewBox="0 0 500 500" >
             <symbol viewBox="0 0 500 500" id="usd">
            <path d="m 145,312 c -2,69 31,100 104,102 78,1 113,-34 109,-101 -6,-58 -62,-73 -106,-79 -48,-17 -99,-25 -99,-95 0,-48 32,-79 99,-78 60,0 97,25 96,84" style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:40" />
            <path d="m 250,15 0,470" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:30" />
        </symbol>
   <use id="usd-usage" xlink:href="#usd" class="sprite-symbol-usage" />

</svg>
```

- Если вы будете многократно использовать спрайт, а он именно для этого
  предназначен, наверняка возникнут вопросы по стилизации
  Для решения можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/709132/28748), [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/609676/28748) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/666763/28748)

Comment: но это не решает проблему того что я не могу нарисовать svg на canvas полотне

Comment: @ClaraOswald отвечено на два основных ваших вопроса: 1.почему спрайт может не отображаться, 2. почему в Firefox могут быть проблемы с отображением svg  Это ваше дело, как относиться к чужому потраченному времени.