# Изменение стилей SVG при ипользовании спрайта

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, svg-спрайт

Как можно изменить стили частей SVG, подключенного через `use`?

Есть SVG с классом `icon`, в нем `use`. 
В `use` SVG c `id="logo"` из спрайта.

Как поменять, например, заливку у `path` с классом `fst6`?

```html
<svg class="icon icon-logo ">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/static/img/svg/symbol/sprite.svg#logo">    </use>
      </svg>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="logo" viewBox="0 0 687.5 235.7" width="100%" height="100%"><path class="fst0" d="M236.6 123.5c0-19.8-12.3-37.2-30.8-43.9.8-4.2 1.2-8.4 1.2-12.7C207 30 177 0 140.2 0 118.6 0 98.6 10.3 86 27.7c-6.2-4.8-13.8-7.4-21.7-7.4-19.6 0-35.5 15.9-35.5 35.5 0 4.3.8 8.5 2.2 12.4-18.4 6.6-31 24.3-31 44 0 19.9 12.4 37.3 30.9 44-.8 4.1-1.2 8.4-1.2 12.7 0 36.8 29.9 66.7 66.7 66.7 21.6 0 41.6-10.4 54.1-27.8 6.2 4.9 13.8 7.6 21.7 7.6 19.6 0 35.5-15.9 35.5-35.5 0-4.3-.8-8.5-2.2-12.4 18.4-6.6 31.1-24.3 31.1-44"></path><path class="fst1" d="M93 101.5l51.8 23.6L197 79.3c.8-3.8 1.1-7.5 1.1-11.5 0-32.2-26.2-58.4-58.4-58.4-19.3 0-37.2 9.5-48.1 25.4l-8.7 45.1L93 101.5z"></path><path class="fst2" d="M39.4 156.3c-.8 3.8-1.1 7.7-1.1 11.7 0 32.3 26.3 58.5 58.6 58.5 19.4 0 37.5-9.6 48.4-25.6l8.6-44.9-11.5-22-52-23.7-51 46z"></path><path class="fst3" d="M39.1 66.7l35.5 8.4 7.8-40.3c-4.8-3.7-10.8-5.7-17-5.7-15.4 0-28 12.5-28 28 0 3.3.6 6.6 1.7 9.6"></path><path class="fst4" d="M36 75.2C20.2 80.4 9.1 95.6 9.1 112.3c0 16.3 10.1 30.8 25.2 36.6l49.8-45L75 84.4l-39-9.2z"></path><path class="fst5" d="M154.3 200.9c4.9 3.7 10.8 5.8 16.9 5.8 15.4 0 28-12.5 28-28 0-3.4-.6-6.7-1.7-9.7l-35.4-8.3-7.8 40.2z"></path><path class="fst6" d="M161.5 151.4l39 9.1c15.9-5.2 26.9-20.4 26.9-37.2 0-16.2-10.1-30.8-25.2-36.5l-51 44.7 10.3 19.9z"></path><path d="M330.8 165.5l4.7-.5.3 9.6c-12.4 1.7-23 2.6-31.8 2.6-11.7 0-20-3.4-24.9-10.2-4.9-6.8-7.3-17.4-7.3-31.7 0-28.6 11.4-42.9 34.1-42.9 11 0 19.2 3.1 24.6 9.2 5.4 6.1 8.1 15.8 8.1 28.9l-.7 9.3h-53.8c0 9 1.6 15.7 4.9 20 3.3 4.3 8.9 6.5 17 6.5 8.2.2 16.4-.1 24.8-.8zm-4.4-35.3c0-10-1.6-17.1-4.8-21.2-3.2-4.1-8.4-6.2-15.6-6.2-7.2 0-12.7 2.2-16.3 6.5-3.6 4.3-5.5 11.3-5.6 20.9h42.3zm29.2 46.5V69.4h12.2v107.3h-12.2zm89.3-57.9v41.1c0 4.1 10.1 3.9 10.1 3.9l-.6 10.8c-8.6 0-15.7.7-20-3.4-9.8 4.3-19.5 6.1-29.3 6.1-7.5 0-13.2-2.1-17.1-6.4-3.9-4.2-5.9-10.3-5.9-18.3 0-7.9 2-13.8 6-17.5 4-3.7 10.3-6.1 18.9-6.9l25.6-2.4v-7c0-5.5-1.2-9.5-3.6-11.9-2.4-2.4-5.7-3.6-9.8-3.6h-32.1V92.5h31.3c9.2 0 15.9 2.1 20.1 6.4 4.3 4.2 6.4 10.9 6.4 19.9zM394.7 152c0 10 4.1 15 12.4 15 7.4 0 14.7-1.2 21.8-3.7l3.7-1.3v-26.9l-24.1 2.3c-4.9.4-8.4 1.8-10.6 4.2-2.2 2.4-3.2 5.9-3.2 10.4zm97.9-48.6c-11.8 0-17.8 4.1-17.8 12.4 0 3.8 1.4 6.5 4.1 8.1 2.7 1.6 8.9 3.2 18.6 4.9 9.7 1.7 16.5 4 20.5 7.1 4 3 6 8.7 6 17.1 0 8.4-2.7 14.5-8.1 18.4-5.4 3.9-13.2 5.9-23.6 5.9-6.7 0-29.2-2.5-29.2-2.5l.7-10.6c12.9 1.2 22.3 2.2 28.6 2.2 6.3 0 11.1-1 14.4-3 3.3-2 5-5.4 5-10.1 0-4.7-1.4-7.9-4.2-9.6-2.8-1.7-9-3.3-18.6-4.8-9.6-1.5-16.4-3.7-20.4-6.7-4-2.9-6-8.4-6-16.3s2.8-13.8 8.4-17.6c5.6-3.8 12.6-5.7 20.9-5.7 6.6 0 29.6 1.7 29.6 1.7V105c-12.1-.7-22-1.6-28.9-1.6zm90.4 1.4h-25.9v39c0 9.3.7 15.5 2 18.4 1.4 2.9 4.6 4.4 9.7 4.4l14.5-1 .8 10.1c-7.3 1.2-12.8 1.8-16.6 1.8-8.5 0-14.3-2.1-17.6-6.2-3.3-4.1-4.9-12-4.9-23.6v-42.9h-11.6V94.2H545v-25h12.1v24.9H583v10.7zm17-21.1V69.6h12.2v14.2H600zm0 93V94.2h12.2v82.5H600zm65.2-84.2c3.6 0 9.7.7 18.3 2l3.9.5-.5 9.9c-8.7-1-15.1-1.5-19.2-1.5-9.2 0-15.5 2.2-18.8 6.6-3.3 4.4-5 12.6-5 24.5s1.5 20.2 4.6 24.9c3.1 4.7 9.5 7 19.3 7l19.2-1.5.5 10.1c-10.1 1.5-17.7 2.3-22.7 2.3-12.7 0-21.5-3.3-26.3-9.8-4.8-6.5-7.3-17.5-7.3-33s2.6-26.4 7.8-32.6c5.3-6.2 14-9.4 26.2-9.4z"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Добавте в вопрос ваш код.

Answer (score 1):

Так и пишите в css: `.fst5 {fill:red;}`

```css
.fst5 {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg class="icon icon-logo ">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/static/img/svg/symbol/sprite.svg#logo">    </use>
      </svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="logo" viewBox="0 0 687.5 235.7" width="100%" height="100%"><path class="fst0" d="M236.6 123.5c0-19.8-12.3-37.2-30.8-43.9.8-4.2 1.2-8.4 1.2-12.7C207 30 177 0 140.2 0 118.6 0 98.6 10.3 86 27.7c-6.2-4.8-13.8-7.4-21.7-7.4-19.6 0-35.5 15.9-35.5 35.5 0 4.3.8 8.5 2.2 12.4-18.4 6.6-31 24.3-31 44 0 19.9 12.4 37.3 30.9 44-.8 4.1-1.2 8.4-1.2 12.7 0 36.8 29.9 66.7 66.7 66.7 21.6 0 41.6-10.4 54.1-27.8 6.2 4.9 13.8 7.6 21.7 7.6 19.6 0 35.5-15.9 35.5-35.5 0-4.3-.8-8.5-2.2-12.4 18.4-6.6 31.1-24.3 31.1-44"></path><path class="fst1" d="M93 101.5l51.8 23.6L197 79.3c.8-3.8 1.1-7.5 1.1-11.5 0-32.2-26.2-58.4-58.4-58.4-19.3 0-37.2 9.5-48.1 25.4l-8.7 45.1L93 101.5z"></path><path class="fst2" d="M39.4 156.3c-.8 3.8-1.1 7.7-1.1 11.7 0 32.3 26.3 58.5 58.6 58.5 19.4 0 37.5-9.6 48.4-25.6l8.6-44.9-11.5-22-52-23.7-51 46z"></path><path class="fst3" d="M39.1 66.7l35.5 8.4 7.8-40.3c-4.8-3.7-10.8-5.7-17-5.7-15.4 0-28 12.5-28 28 0 3.3.6 6.6 1.7 9.6"></path><path class="fst4" d="M36 75.2C20.2 80.4 9.1 95.6 9.1 112.3c0 16.3 10.1 30.8 25.2 36.6l49.8-45L75 84.4l-39-9.2z"></path><path class="fst5" d="M154.3 200.9c4.9 3.7 10.8 5.8 16.9 5.8 15.4 0 28-12.5 28-28 0-3.4-.6-6.7-1.7-9.7l-35.4-8.3-7.8 40.2z"></path><path class="fst6" d="M161.5 151.4l39 9.1c15.9-5.2 26.9-20.4 26.9-37.2 0-16.2-10.1-30.8-25.2-36.5l-51 44.7 10.3 19.9z"></path><path d="M330.8 165.5l4.7-.5.3 9.6c-12.4 1.7-23 2.6-31.8 2.6-11.7 0-20-3.4-24.9-10.2-4.9-6.8-7.3-17.4-7.3-31.7 0-28.6 11.4-42.9 34.1-42.9 11 0 19.2 3.1 24.6 9.2 5.4 6.1 8.1 15.8 8.1 28.9l-.7 9.3h-53.8c0 9 1.6 15.7 4.9 20 3.3 4.3 8.9 6.5 17 6.5 8.2.2 16.4-.1 24.8-.8zm-4.4-35.3c0-10-1.6-17.1-4.8-21.2-3.2-4.1-8.4-6.2-15.6-6.2-7.2 0-12.7 2.2-16.3 6.5-3.6 4.3-5.5 11.3-5.6 20.9h42.3zm29.2 46.5V69.4h12.2v107.3h-12.2zm89.3-57.9v41.1c0 4.1 10.1 3.9 10.1 3.9l-.6 10.8c-8.6 0-15.7.7-20-3.4-9.8 4.3-19.5 6.1-29.3 6.1-7.5 0-13.2-2.1-17.1-6.4-3.9-4.2-5.9-10.3-5.9-18.3 0-7.9 2-13.8 6-17.5 4-3.7 10.3-6.1 18.9-6.9l25.6-2.4v-7c0-5.5-1.2-9.5-3.6-11.9-2.4-2.4-5.7-3.6-9.8-3.6h-32.1V92.5h31.3c9.2 0 15.9 2.1 20.1 6.4 4.3 4.2 6.4 10.9 6.4 19.9zM394.7 152c0 10 4.1 15 12.4 15 7.4 0 14.7-1.2 21.8-3.7l3.7-1.3v-26.9l-24.1 2.3c-4.9.4-8.4 1.8-10.6 4.2-2.2 2.4-3.2 5.9-3.2 10.4zm97.9-48.6c-11.8 0-17.8 4.1-17.8 12.4 0 3.8 1.4 6.5 4.1 8.1 2.7 1.6 8.9 3.2 18.6 4.9 9.7 1.7 16.5 4 20.5 7.1 4 3 6 8.7 6 17.1 0 8.4-2.7 14.5-8.1 18.4-5.4 3.9-13.2 5.9-23.6 5.9-6.7 0-29.2-2.5-29.2-2.5l.7-10.6c12.9 1.2 22.3 2.2 28.6 2.2 6.3 0 11.1-1 14.4-3 3.3-2 5-5.4 5-10.1 0-4.7-1.4-7.9-4.2-9.6-2.8-1.7-9-3.3-18.6-4.8-9.6-1.5-16.4-3.7-20.4-6.7-4-2.9-6-8.4-6-16.3s2.8-13.8 8.4-17.6c5.6-3.8 12.6-5.7 20.9-5.7 6.6 0 29.6 1.7 29.6 1.7V105c-12.1-.7-22-1.6-28.9-1.6zm90.4 1.4h-25.9v39c0 9.3.7 15.5 2 18.4 1.4 2.9 4.6 4.4 9.7 4.4l14.5-1 .8 10.1c-7.3 1.2-12.8 1.8-16.6 1.8-8.5 0-14.3-2.1-17.6-6.2-3.3-4.1-4.9-12-4.9-23.6v-42.9h-11.6V94.2H545v-25h12.1v24.9H583v10.7zm17-21.1V69.6h12.2v14.2H600zm0 93V94.2h12.2v82.5H600zm65.2-84.2c3.6 0 9.7.7 18.3 2l3.9.5-.5 9.9c-8.7-1-15.1-1.5-19.2-1.5-9.2 0-15.5 2.2-18.8 6.6-3.3 4.4-5 12.6-5 24.5s1.5 20.2 4.6 24.9c3.1 4.7 9.5 7 19.3 7l19.2-1.5.5 10.1c-10.1 1.5-17.7 2.3-22.7 2.3-12.7 0-21.5-3.3-26.3-9.8-4.8-6.5-7.3-17.5-7.3-33s2.6-26.4 7.8-32.6c5.3-6.2 14-9.4 26.2-9.4z"></path></svg>
```

Как вариант, можно объявлять CSS непосредственно в самом SVG:

```html
<svg class="icon icon-logo ">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/static/img/svg/symbol/sprite.svg#logo">    </use>
      </svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="logo" viewBox="0 0 687.5 235.7" width="100%" height="100%">
  <style>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    .fst5 {
      fill: red;
    }
    /* ]]> */
  </style>
<path class="fst0" d="M236.6 123.5c0-19.8-12.3-37.2-30.8-43.9.8-4.2 1.2-8.4 1.2-12.7C207 30 177 0 140.2 0 118.6 0 98.6 10.3 86 27.7c-6.2-4.8-13.8-7.4-21.7-7.4-19.6 0-35.5 15.9-35.5 35.5 0 4.3.8 8.5 2.2 12.4-18.4 6.6-31 24.3-31 44 0 19.9 12.4 37.3 30.9 44-.8 4.1-1.2 8.4-1.2 12.7 0 36.8 29.9 66.7 66.7 66.7 21.6 0 41.6-10.4 54.1-27.8 6.2 4.9 13.8 7.6 21.7 7.6 19.6 0 35.5-15.9 35.5-35.5 0-4.3-.8-8.5-2.2-12.4 18.4-6.6 31.1-24.3 31.1-44"></path><path class="fst1" d="M93 101.5l51.8 23.6L197 79.3c.8-3.8 1.1-7.5 1.1-11.5 0-32.2-26.2-58.4-58.4-58.4-19.3 0-37.2 9.5-48.1 25.4l-8.7 45.1L93 101.5z"></path><path class="fst2" d="M39.4 156.3c-.8 3.8-1.1 7.7-1.1 11.7 0 32.3 26.3 58.5 58.6 58.5 19.4 0 37.5-9.6 48.4-25.6l8.6-44.9-11.5-22-52-23.7-51 46z"></path><path class="fst3" d="M39.1 66.7l35.5 8.4 7.8-40.3c-4.8-3.7-10.8-5.7-17-5.7-15.4 0-28 12.5-28 28 0 3.3.6 6.6 1.7 9.6"></path><path class="fst4" d="M36 75.2C20.2 80.4 9.1 95.6 9.1 112.3c0 16.3 10.1 30.8 25.2 36.6l49.8-45L75 84.4l-39-9.2z"></path><path class="fst5" d="M154.3 200.9c4.9 3.7 10.8 5.8 16.9 5.8 15.4 0 28-12.5 28-28 0-3.4-.6-6.7-1.7-9.7l-35.4-8.3-7.8 40.2z"></path><path class="fst6" d="M161.5 151.4l39 9.1c15.9-5.2 26.9-20.4 26.9-37.2 0-16.2-10.1-30.8-25.2-36.5l-51 44.7 10.3 19.9z"></path><path d="M330.8 165.5l4.7-.5.3 9.6c-12.4 1.7-23 2.6-31.8 2.6-11.7 0-20-3.4-24.9-10.2-4.9-6.8-7.3-17.4-7.3-31.7 0-28.6 11.4-42.9 34.1-42.9 11 0 19.2 3.1 24.6 9.2 5.4 6.1 8.1 15.8 8.1 28.9l-.7 9.3h-53.8c0 9 1.6 15.7 4.9 20 3.3 4.3 8.9 6.5 17 6.5 8.2.2 16.4-.1 24.8-.8zm-4.4-35.3c0-10-1.6-17.1-4.8-21.2-3.2-4.1-8.4-6.2-15.6-6.2-7.2 0-12.7 2.2-16.3 6.5-3.6 4.3-5.5 11.3-5.6 20.9h42.3zm29.2 46.5V69.4h12.2v107.3h-12.2zm89.3-57.9v41.1c0 4.1 10.1 3.9 10.1 3.9l-.6 10.8c-8.6 0-15.7.7-20-3.4-9.8 4.3-19.5 6.1-29.3 6.1-7.5 0-13.2-2.1-17.1-6.4-3.9-4.2-5.9-10.3-5.9-18.3 0-7.9 2-13.8 6-17.5 4-3.7 10.3-6.1 18.9-6.9l25.6-2.4v-7c0-5.5-1.2-9.5-3.6-11.9-2.4-2.4-5.7-3.6-9.8-3.6h-32.1V92.5h31.3c9.2 0 15.9 2.1 20.1 6.4 4.3 4.2 6.4 10.9 6.4 19.9zM394.7 152c0 10 4.1 15 12.4 15 7.4 0 14.7-1.2 21.8-3.7l3.7-1.3v-26.9l-24.1 2.3c-4.9.4-8.4 1.8-10.6 4.2-2.2 2.4-3.2 5.9-3.2 10.4zm97.9-48.6c-11.8 0-17.8 4.1-17.8 12.4 0 3.8 1.4 6.5 4.1 8.1 2.7 1.6 8.9 3.2 18.6 4.9 9.7 1.7 16.5 4 20.5 7.1 4 3 6 8.7 6 17.1 0 8.4-2.7 14.5-8.1 18.4-5.4 3.9-13.2 5.9-23.6 5.9-6.7 0-29.2-2.5-29.2-2.5l.7-10.6c12.9 1.2 22.3 2.2 28.6 2.2 6.3 0 11.1-1 14.4-3 3.3-2 5-5.4 5-10.1 0-4.7-1.4-7.9-4.2-9.6-2.8-1.7-9-3.3-18.6-4.8-9.6-1.5-16.4-3.7-20.4-6.7-4-2.9-6-8.4-6-16.3s2.8-13.8 8.4-17.6c5.6-3.8 12.6-5.7 20.9-5.7 6.6 0 29.6 1.7 29.6 1.7V105c-12.1-.7-22-1.6-28.9-1.6zm90.4 1.4h-25.9v39c0 9.3.7 15.5 2 18.4 1.4 2.9 4.6 4.4 9.7 4.4l14.5-1 .8 10.1c-7.3 1.2-12.8 1.8-16.6 1.8-8.5 0-14.3-2.1-17.6-6.2-3.3-4.1-4.9-12-4.9-23.6v-42.9h-11.6V94.2H545v-25h12.1v24.9H583v10.7zm17-21.1V69.6h12.2v14.2H600zm0 93V94.2h12.2v82.5H600zm65.2-84.2c3.6 0 9.7.7 18.3 2l3.9.5-.5 9.9c-8.7-1-15.1-1.5-19.2-1.5-9.2 0-15.5 2.2-18.8 6.6-3.3 4.4-5 12.6-5 24.5s1.5 20.2 4.6 24.9c3.1 4.7 9.5 7 19.3 7l19.2-1.5.5 10.1c-10.1 1.5-17.7 2.3-22.7 2.3-12.7 0-21.5-3.3-26.3-9.8-4.8-6.5-7.3-17.5-7.3-33s2.6-26.4 7.8-32.6c5.3-6.2 14-9.4 26.2-9.4z"></path></svg>
```

Comment: Таким способом не работает

Comment: @ИгорьМясников Как видите из сниппета, все работает. С чем именно у вас проблема?

Comment: Если просто SVG подключить без спрайта - то все стили работают отлично. Но при подключении через use - работают только стили для всего SVG, а для разных частей (path) не применяются

Comment: @ИгорьМясников Повторюсь - по сниппету видно, что все работает исправно. Вы уверены, что верный SVG приложили к вопросу?

Comment: да он пока один

Comment: @ИгорьМясников значит, вы неверно прописываете стили css

Comment: Все проверял и применял стили к классу по разному - ничего.

Comment: Применяется только на Use (use {fill:red}) и все

Comment: @ИгорьМясников а какие в DevTools у вас отображаются стили при выборе необходимого path?

Comment: Никаких стилей , даже если я напрямую в DevTools их указываю

Comment: @ИгорьМясников добавил в ответ еще один метод.

Comment: В gulp обрезается все встроенные  Style, Fill, Stroke иначе через css их не поменяешь - приоритет выше.

Comment: Хотя я и отменял сейчас эти действия по удалению стилей - все равно ничего. Стили в самом скачанном SVG уже прописаны

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Решил вопрос

Comment: @ИгорьМясников и в чем же была проблема?

Comment: @ИгорьМясников Вопрос должен быть закрыт. Если вы самостоятельно решили проблему приведите свой код и сами поставьте себе галочку правилами это вполне допустимо, если не хотите это сделать по тем или иным соображениям, то выбирайте ответ и закрывайте вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

> Как можно изменить стили частей SVG, подключенного через use?

При использовании команды повторного вызова <kbd>use</kbd>,
элемент svg попадает в теневой дом (shadow DOM) и становится недоступным для управления из внешней таблицы стилей.

Для устранения этого применяется принудительное наследование свойств :

```
svg path 
{
fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
}
```

далее уже можно применять правила css для закраски патчей и строк.

```
#fst0{
fill:#d3d3d3;

}
#fst1{
fill:yellowgreen;
}
```

*Обратите внимание*, что вызов элементов svg командой use используется через **#id**, поэтому необходимо заменить **классы** на уникальные идентификаторы.

К сожалению я не могу продемонстрировать здесь вызов частей кода из отдельного файла SVG, расположенного на другом ресурсе. Но можно промоделировать этот механизм, обернув весь код в `<symbol>.... </symbol>`, тем самым весь код станет невидимым до вызова его частей командой use.

**Ниже пример стилизации при использовании use**

```css
svg path 
{
fill:inherit;
stroke:inherit;
}
#fst0, #elem{
fill:#d3d3d3;

}
#fst1{
fill:yellowgreen;
}  
#fst2{
fill:yellow;
} 
#fst3{
fill:sandybrown;
}
#fst4{
fill:crimson;
}
#fst5{
fill:mediumseagreen;
} 
#fst6{
fill:skyblue;
}
```

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="logo" viewBox="0 0 687.5 235.7" width="100%" height="100%">
 <symbol id="symb">
 <path id="fst0" d="M236.6 123.5c0-19.8-12.3-37.2-30.8-43.9.8-4.2 1.2-8.4 1.2-12.7C207 30 177 0 140.2 0 118.6 0 98.6 10.3 86 27.7c-6.2-4.8-13.8-7.4-21.7-7.4-19.6 0-35.5 15.9-35.5 35.5 0 4.3.8 8.5 2.2 12.4-18.4 6.6-31 24.3-31 44 0 19.9 12.4 37.3 30.9 44-.8 4.1-1.2 8.4-1.2 12.7 0 36.8 29.9 66.7 66.7 66.7 21.6 0 41.6-10.4 54.1-27.8 6.2 4.9 13.8 7.6 21.7 7.6 19.6 0 35.5-15.9 35.5-35.5 0-4.3-.8-8.5-2.2-12.4 18.4-6.6 31.1-24.3 31.1-44">
 </path>
 <path id="fst1" d="M93 101.5l51.8 23.6L197 79.3c.8-3.8 1.1-7.5 1.1-11.5 0-32.2-26.2-58.4-58.4-58.4-19.3 0-37.2 9.5-48.1 25.4l-8.7 45.1L93 101.5z">
 </path>
 <path id="fst2" d="M39.4 156.3c-.8 3.8-1.1 7.7-1.1 11.7 0 32.3 26.3 58.5 58.6 58.5 19.4 0 37.5-9.6 48.4-25.6l8.6-44.9-11.5-22-52-23.7-51 46z">
 </path>
 <path id="fst3" d="M39.1 66.7l35.5 8.4 7.8-40.3c-4.8-3.7-10.8-5.7-17-5.7-15.4 0-28 12.5-28 28 0 3.3.6 6.6 1.7 9.6">
 </path>
 <path id="fst4" d="M36 75.2C20.2 80.4 9.1 95.6 9.1 112.3c0 16.3 10.1 30.8 25.2 36.6l49.8-45L75 84.4l-39-9.2z">
 </path>
 <path id="fst5" d="M154.3 200.9c4.9 3.7 10.8 5.8 16.9 5.8 15.4 0 28-12.5 28-28 0-3.4-.6-6.7-1.7-9.7l-35.4-8.3-7.8 40.2z">
 </path>
 <path id="fst6" d="M161.5 151.4l39 9.1c15.9-5.2 26.9-20.4 26.9-37.2 0-16.2-10.1-30.8-25.2-36.5l-51 44.7 10.3 19.9z">
 </path>
 <path id="elem" d="M330.8 165.5l4.7-.5.3 9.6c-12.4 1.7-23 2.6-31.8 2.6-11.7 0-20-3.4-24.9-10.2-4.9-6.8-7.3-17.4-7.3-31.7 0-28.6 11.4-42.9 34.1-42.9 11 0 19.2 3.1 24.6 9.2 5.4 6.1 8.1 15.8 8.1 28.9l-.7 9.3h-53.8c0 9 1.6 15.7 4.9 20 3.3 4.3 8.9 6.5 17 6.5 8.2.2 16.4-.1 24.8-.8zm-4.4-35.3c0-10-1.6-17.1-4.8-21.2-3.2-4.1-8.4-6.2-15.6-6.2-7.2 0-12.7 2.2-16.3 6.5-3.6 4.3-5.5 11.3-5.6 20.9h42.3zm29.2 46.5V69.4h12.2v107.3h-12.2zm89.3-57.9v41.1c0 4.1 10.1 3.9 10.1 3.9l-.6 10.8c-8.6 0-15.7.7-20-3.4-9.8 4.3-19.5 6.1-29.3 6.1-7.5 0-13.2-2.1-17.1-6.4-3.9-4.2-5.9-10.3-5.9-18.3 0-7.9 2-13.8 6-17.5 4-3.7 10.3-6.1 18.9-6.9l25.6-2.4v-7c0-5.5-1.2-9.5-3.6-11.9-2.4-2.4-5.7-3.6-9.8-3.6h-32.1V92.5h31.3c9.2 0 15.9 2.1 20.1 6.4 4.3 4.2 6.4 10.9 6.4 19.9zM394.7 152c0 10 4.1 15 12.4 15 7.4 0 14.7-1.2 21.8-3.7l3.7-1.3v-26.9l-24.1 2.3c-4.9.4-8.4 1.8-10.6 4.2-2.2 2.4-3.2 5.9-3.2 10.4zm97.9-48.6c-11.8 0-17.8 4.1-17.8 12.4 0 3.8 1.4 6.5 4.1 8.1 2.7 1.6 8.9 3.2 18.6 4.9 9.7 1.7 16.5 4 20.5 7.1 4 3 6 8.7 6 17.1 0 8.4-2.7 14.5-8.1 18.4-5.4 3.9-13.2 5.9-23.6 5.9-6.7 0-29.2-2.5-29.2-2.5l.7-10.6c12.9 1.2 22.3 2.2 28.6 2.2 6.3 0 11.1-1 14.4-3 3.3-2 5-5.4 5-10.1 0-4.7-1.4-7.9-4.2-9.6-2.8-1.7-9-3.3-18.6-4.8-9.6-1.5-16.4-3.7-20.4-6.7-4-2.9-6-8.4-6-16.3s2.8-13.8 8.4-17.6c5.6-3.8 12.6-5.7 20.9-5.7 6.6 0 29.6 1.7 29.6 1.7V105c-12.1-.7-22-1.6-28.9-1.6zm90.4 1.4h-25.9v39c0 9.3.7 15.5 2 18.4 1.4 2.9 4.6 4.4 9.7 4.4l14.5-1 .8 10.1c-7.3 1.2-12.8 1.8-16.6 1.8-8.5 0-14.3-2.1-17.6-6.2-3.3-4.1-4.9-12-4.9-23.6v-42.9h-11.6V94.2H545v-25h12.1v24.9H583v10.7zm17-21.1V69.6h12.2v14.2H600zm0 93V94.2h12.2v82.5H600zm65.2-84.2c3.6 0 9.7.7 18.3 2l3.9.5-.5 9.9c-8.7-1-15.1-1.5-19.2-1.5-9.2 0-15.5 2.2-18.8 6.6-3.3 4.4-5 12.6-5 24.5s1.5 20.2 4.6 24.9c3.1 4.7 9.5 7 19.3 7l19.2-1.5.5 10.1c-10.1 1.5-17.7 2.3-22.7 2.3-12.7 0-21.5-3.3-26.3-9.8-4.8-6.5-7.3-17.5-7.3-33s2.6-26.4 7.8-32.6c5.3-6.2 14-9.4 26.2-9.4z"></path>
 </symbol>
 <use xlink:href="#fst0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#fst1"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#fst2"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#fst2"></use>
    <use xlink:href="#fst3"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#fst4"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#fst5"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#fst6"></use>
    <use xlink:href="#elem"></use>
 
 </svg>
```